# Decode URI in Jmeter Groovy

Tags: groovy, jmeter, beanshell

Below is the snippet of code from Java Script.

```
  location = response.headers['Location'];
  location = decodeURI(location);
```

Is there a way to decode URI in Jmeter Groovy?

Answer (score 0):

There is [__urldecode() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urldecode) available in JMeter

Given [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI#decoding_a_cyrillic_url)

```
decodeURI('https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/JavaScript_%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8B');
// "https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/JavaScript_шеллы"
```

If you invoke `${__urldecode(https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/JavaScript_%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8B)}` - you will get the same result

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)